# Can't see the metadata for my sepolia nft on opensea's testnet or ehterscan testnet

Tags: nft, erc-721, meta-data

I'm following a tutorial on how to create an ERC721 contract and I've ran into a problem. I can't see the image for an NFT I've minted on Opensea's testnet. none of the metadata will load after almost 24 hours and multiple refreshes.

The nft collection:

https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/forsens

The nft's metadata: https://ipfs.filebase.io/ipfs/QmPR6z3JM8vtUe1PNRsUD6CtBbu3yTt1PaKjNhkG3LWduH/QmUvcr9d9XTgwTNYf9tBGcdpEcgGFdy5kCaqdVZEVmzKLL

Remix does show the the 0 token has been minted and that it has the accurate ipfs hash

[image]

The tutorial in question:

https://youtu.be/veBu03A6ptw?si=pU1zYqTMwZffhF64&t=2288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmPR6z3JM8vtUe1PNRsUD6CtBbu3yTt1PaKjNhkG3LWduH/`
This is a directory or folder, not a json file.

[image]

If you set tokenURI(0) to `ipfs://QmPR6z3JM8vtUe1PNRsUD6CtBbu3yTt1PaKjNhkG3LWduH/QmUvcr9d9XTgwTNYf9tBGcdpEcgGFdy5kCaqdVZEVmzKLL` OR `ipfs://QmUvcr9d9XTgwTNYf9tBGcdpEcgGFdy5kCaqdVZEVmzKLL`, you may be able to display the metadata.